# how to repair multiple addons with the same name found?

Tags: add-on, makehuman

my add-ons file shows this error message but when I go to the Blender files
there is no corresponding file to the message,

" multiple addons with the same name found "

Please delete one of each pair

Make Clothes:

C\User\thund\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\makeclothes_init_.py

C:\User\thund\AppData\Roaming\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\maketarget.py

when I go to these files there is no makeclothes or target file. I have also dumped the addon where it is no longer showing in the Addon list and even uninstalled Blender and reinstalled , and deleted my  Blender files before reload however I did not dump the user files in my docs but checked and these files are not there ether , but when I reloaded the add-ons I got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late on this, but it still seems to be there. Captured it today while upgrading from 3.51 to 3.6.

The Blender installation sets up its folder structure by default, in `%appdata%\roaming\blenderfoundation\blender\VERSION\scripts`.

When starting a new version, you will be prompted to accept the old settings found. I say *Yes* and it works as expected and copies all the addons to its new scripts folder and it also inherits the FILE PATHS environment from the older version. Here it sees the old version path and the copied add-ons twice from now on.

Solution: Give the new Blender version the new script path in the FILE PATHS settings. - It works fine for me

Comment: Comment to mechanic: 
You right, its up to the user to find his own unusually created file paths. What I said works for me and I think for the most usually installed file paths in Blender too.

Answer (score -2):

Check in the scripts/addons directory where the blender is installed.

Comment: And then what? Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn about how to write a good answer.

Comment: There are two locations for blender to look for its add-ons. One is in the user's AppData, and another is in the blender_install_dir/scripts/addons. So if they are not located in one of them, then probably they are located in another. And then what - it's up to the user.
And about a good answer. Maybe I'm a bit stupid, but I'm sure that one who looks for a file needs the file location, not the good answer. ;-)